# keyboard input data type in python

Tags: python

I am currently working in an embedded project. In my project I want to compare two values.

The first value is an integer(0) and the second one is the keyboard input (and it also should be an integer).

Whenever I try running the code it shows:

```
{TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()}
```

How to overcome this TypeError?

The code is:

```
import sys
import time
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import collections

c = collections.Counter()
c=0


required_position=0
current_position=0
pulse_generated=0
req=0

gpio.setwarnings(False)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(23,gpio.OUT)           
gpio.setup(24,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(9,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(10,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(13,gpio.OUT)
gpio.setup(19,gpio.OUT)

mode_1=(8,10,15)
gpio.setup(mode_1,gpio.OUT)
mode_1=(17,27,22)
gpio.setup(mode_1,gpio.OUT)
resolution={
    '1':(0,0,0),
    '1/2':(1,0,0),
    '1/4':(0,1,0),
    '1/8':(1,1,0),
    '1/16':(0,0,1),
    '1/32':(1,0,1),
    }


def current_position_calculation():
    global required_position
    global current_position
    global pulse_generated
    current_position=pulse_generated*6

def required_distance():
    global required_position
    global current_position
    global pulse_generated
    print('position of stepper motor are'
            'z for homeposition(0 deg)',
            'a for 10 degree',
            'b for 20 degree',
            'd for 30 degree',
            'e for 40 degree',
            'f for 50 degree',
            'g for 60 degree',)

    req=input("choose your required position")
    required_position=req
    if required_position==current_position:
        gpio.output(23,True)
        while current_position!=required_position:
            gpio.output(24,True)
            time.sleep(t)
            gpio.output(24,False)
            time.sleep(t)
            current_position+=1
            c+=1
    elif current_position<required_position:
        gpio.output(23,False)
        while current_position>required_position:
            gpio.output(24,True)
            time.sleep(t)
            gpio.output(24,False)
            time.sleep(t)
            current_position-=1
            c-=1
def previous_position():
    global required_position
    global current_position
    global pulse_generated
    if current_position>required_position:
        pulse_generated=required_position-currentposition
    elif current_position<required_position:
        pulse_generated=currentposition-required_position

while True:
    current_position_calculation()
    required_distance()
    previous_position()
```

here is my full code with initialisation.

The mcve of my code is

```
import sys
import time

a=0
b=input("enter the value ")

if a<b:
    a+=1
    print(a)
else:
    a-=1
    print(a)
```

error:

```
enter the value a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mcve.py", line 7, in <module>
    if a<b:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
>>>
```

for entering integer value:

```
enter the value 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/mcve.py", line 7, in <module>
    if a<b:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
>>>
```

Comment: Please extend your [mcve] to actually demosntrate the problem. Provide initialisations of the used variables and drop any unrelated code, e.g. `gpio()`.

Comment: Be careful with indentation, e.g. around `elif`. Be careful with non-code, e.g. "thank you guys!!".

Comment: The MCVE is important, because when I try to recreate your problem with the given information, I get a different error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`.

Comment: is there any way to get keyboard input as an integer??

Comment: Yes there is. Please make a more minimal MCVE to provide a foundation for an efficient answer.

Comment: what is actually MCVE is??

Comment: An MCVE is a [mcve].

Comment: hey,am provided the mcve of my code!!

Comment: With python 2.7.15 (from IDLE) the mcve works fine. With python 3.7.0 (explicit script parameter from comandline) I still get the different error quoted in my comment above. Can you double check that your mcve demonstrates the error you quote? Which python are you using?

Comment: My earlier comment was caused by the long code still being there and before the (good) MCVE. Sorry for its tone by the way. But you might consider removing the long version and only keeping the MCVE. If the MCVE does not cover any detail you consider relevant, then please extend it (it should still be complete to show everything you want to discuss) within the frame of being minimal. That way the question is probably better received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'`, and only with Python 3.7.0, not with Python 2.7.15.

However, that error I can fix with

```
if a<int(b):
```

instead of

```
if a<b:
```

Maybe your error (which I cannot reproduce) gets fixed that way, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for casting in python.

Any type of data type conversion will go under the heading "casting" and you can easily find examples.